# System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted

Tags: c#, system.text.json

I'm using Ubuntu and dotnet 3.1, running vscode's c# extension.

I need to create a List from a JSON file, my controller will do some calculations with this model List that I will pass to it

So, here is my code and the error I'm getting.

First, I thought my error was because at model my attributes were char and C#, for what I saw, cannot interpret double-quotes for char, it should be single quotes. Before losing time removing it, I just changed my type declarations to strings and it's the same error.

Can someone help me?

ElevadorModel

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Bla
{
    public class ElevadorModel
    {
        public int andar { get; set; }
        public string elevador { get; set; }
        public string turno { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var path = "../input.json";

        string jsonString;
        
        ElevadorModel elevadoresModel = new ElevadorModel();

        jsonString = File.ReadAllText(path); //GetType().Name = String

        Console.WriteLine(jsonString); //WORKS           

        elevadoresModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ElevadorModel>(jsonString);
    }
```

JSON:

[image]

Comment: You haven't shown us a snippet of the JSON that reproduced the problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your input json has an array as the base token, whereas you're expecting an object.  You need to change your deserialization to an array of objects.

```
var elevadoresModels = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ElevadorModel>>(jsonString);
elevadoresModel = elavoresModels.First();
```

Comment: hi, i'm new to c#. This is the correct way of initialize my list of objects now, right? List<ElevadorModel> elevadoresModel = new List<ElevadorModel>();

Comment: Correct, list instantiation is done via `new List<Type>()`.  That said, in this case you do not need to initialize the list beforehand.  The deserializer will create the collection for you.  In my example, `var` is just compiler inference for `List<ElevadorModel>`.  You can use either interchangeably in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Your input JSON is an array of models, however you're trying to deserialize it to a single model.

```cs
var models = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ElevadorModel>>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is also a problem in Blazor-Client side. For those calling a single object 
e.g `ClassName  = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<ClassName>($"api/ClassName/{id}");`

This will fail to Deserialize. Using the same System.Text.Json it can be done by: 
 `List<ClassName> ListName  = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<ClassName>>($"api/ClassName/{id}");` 
You can use an array or a list. For some reason System.Text.Json, does not give errors and it is successfully able Deserialize.

To access your object, knowing that it is a single object use:
`ListName[0].Property` 
In your case the latter solution is fine but with the path as the input.

Comment: Isn't that essentially what the other answers stated, however, you don't clearly mention that the root cause was deserializing to a single object instead of a collection

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was pulling the JSON data to deserialize out of an HTTP response body. It looked like this:

```
var resp = await _client.GetAsync($"{endpoint}");    
var respBody = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var listOfInstances = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<modelType>>(respBody);
```

And the error would show up. Upon further investigation, I found the respBody string had the JSON base object (an array) wrapped in double quotes...something like this:

```
"[{\"prop\":\"value\"},...]"
```

So I added

```
respBody = respBody.Trim('\"');
```

And the error changed! Now it was pointing to an invalid character '\'.
I changed that line to include

```
respBody = respBody.Trim('\"').Replace("\\", "");
```

and it began to deserialize perfectly.

For reference:

```
var resp = await _client.GetAsync($"{endpoint}");    
var respBody = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
respBody = respBody.Trim('\"').Replace("\\", "");
var listOfInstances = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<modelType>>(respBody);
```